# How to make Lynx COLUMN width infinite?

Tags: lynx

```
   -width=NUMBER
          number of columns for formatting of dumps, default is 80.
```

**My question:** "-width=999999" is not so good.. "-width=0" isn't working. How can I give the "-width" an infinite number?

UPDATE: I am just trying to download a txt file (that has longer lines) with:

```
lynx --dump foo.com/bar.txt
```

Comment: Are you using it to dump data or actually browse with it?

Comment: Then a `<hr>` would turn into an infinitely long horizontal rule. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: updated the question

Comment: Hm, any reason for not using `wget`, `curl`? Or even `nc`?

Answer (score 1):

short: you can't do this with lynx

long: the **`-width`** option applies to **formatted** output.  `wget` and `curl` do not format their output (those are comparable to the **`-source`** option of Lynx).

Formatted output pertains to what you see on the screen.  Except for demonstration purposes, your screen will be no more than a few hundred columns of text (usually much less).

While *most* fixed-length buffers have been rewritten in the source code, the maximum line-length for formatted output from Lynx is still a compiled-in constant (1024).  Changing that is more than simply changing a number and recompiling, because Lynx manages memory pools which include data structures containing these (fixed-length lines).  If you increased the maximum length of a line, then that would change the block-size used for the memory pool (or make it less efficient by storing fewer lines in a block).

The command-line `-width` option is limited because of this, in the [main program](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/lynx-snapshots/blob/master/src/LYMain.c#L3303):

```c
/* -width */
static int width_fun(char *next_arg)
{
    if (next_arg != 0) {
    int w = atoi(next_arg);

    if (w > 0)
        dump_output_width = ((w < MAX_COLS) ? w : MAX_COLS);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Further reading: [src/GridText.c](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/lynx-snapshots/blob/master/src/GridText.c#L147), where the relevant data structures are defined.